# Close VIM session over ssh

Tags: vim, remote, vi

I work remotely some days and I left vim open with some unsaved changes at the office. Now I'd like to save and close those sessions so I can work on those files at home. I am logged into that machine over SSH. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2760014/94928) over at Stack Overflow.