# vim serverlist over ssh doesn't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

I was trying to play with vim server instances and noticed when I SSH into my work box I can never see the names of the server - so I can't send signals to them

as you will see, if I create a server instance locally and then exit to the shell I can list out (and see) whats available. But if I SSH into work, then I can't do the same thing?  I also tried this process starting from work to my house but got the same results.

My end goal is to be able to [remotely close](https://superuser.com/questions/220756/close-vim-session-over-ssh) some vim sessions I have open b/c my RDP keeps flaking out

```
> ┌─(veilig@kanga:pts/2)───────────────────────────────────────────────────(~)─┐
> └─(12:09:%)── vim --servername VIMLOCAL foo.txt               
> ──(Sat,Apr21)─┘
> 
> ┌─(veilig@kanga:pts/2)───────────────────────────────────────────────────(~)─┐
> └─(12:09:%)── vim --serverlist                                
> ──(Sat,Apr21)─┘ VIMLOCAL
>
>
> ┌─(veilig@kanga:pts/2)───────────────────────────────────────────────────(~)─┐
> └─(12:09:%)── ssh jamiek@work                                 
> ──(Sat,Apr21)─┘ Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-17-generic
> x86_64)
> 
> Last login: Sat Apr 21 12:03:13 2012
> ┌─(jamiek@work:pts/12)────────────────────────────────────────────(~)─┐
> └─(12:10:%)── vim --servername VIMLOCAL foo.txt               
> ──(Sat,Apr21)─┘
> 
> ┌─(jamiek@work:pts/12)────────────────────────────────────────────(~)─┐
> └─(12:10:%)── vim --serverlist                                
> ──(Sat,Apr21)─┘
> ┌─(jamiek@work:pts/12)────────────────────────────────────────────(~)─┐
> └─(12:10:%)── exit                                            
> ──(Sat,Apr21)─┘ Connection to work closed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out!  vim ends up using X properties to communicate, so when SSHing and trying to use this feature you have to allow X11 forwarding.

this post helped me out!

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9080/is-it-possible-to-run-a-vim-clientserver-instance-over-sshtmux